# Importing trusted authority key in tomcat

Tags: tomcat, ssl

I want to deploy a trusted CA key on tomcat, but I am facing with some problems. I went through the documentation, and some other resources on net, I get a few errors. I will describe first the keys I have.

1. server.crt : This is the key which is provided by the hosting guys, it's the server's key on which tomcat is there
2. TrustedCA.crt : This is the SSL key provided by CA authorities which I want to deploy.

As per the documentation, if I go and give the following command :

```
keytool -genkey -alias tomcat -keyalg RSA
```

and then add the the TrustedCA.crt with the flag -trustcacerts, then also I see an exception from Mozilla saying

```
The key used on this site is self signed
```

If I dont do step 1, and I just plain import the TrustedCA.crt with alias as tomcat, then I get the error as follows :

```
ssl_error_no_cypher_overlap
```

I just can't figure out what I am doing wrong. Tomcat is configured to use the SSL connection with the following config in server.xml :

```
<Connector port="8443"  protocol="HTTP/1.1" SSLEnabled="true"
maxThreads="150" scheme="https" secure="true" keystoreFile="/home/akshay/keystore/.keystore"
keystorePass="password" clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS"/>
```

Also, if I try to use the command mentioned below which is from Apache SSL guide, then I have the error as No Certificates loaded.

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -in mycert.crt -inkey mykey.key \
                        -out mycert.p12 -name tomcat -CAfile myCA.crt \
                        -caname root -chain
```

I don't understand what is going wrong. Any help would be nice. Thank you very much.

Comment: Don't you want to use Self signed certificate ?

Comment: I have a the certificate which is signed by a trusted authority, which is TrustedCA.crt , I want to use that. Am I understanding something wrong here?

Comment: I would suggest to create self signed certificate first, then navigate to trusted CA

Comment: This is done by using keytool -genkey -alias tomcat -keyalg RSA, correct? If I do that and import the .crt file -import -trustedcacerts, then I get an error as the certificate is self signed.

Comment: That is just the warning which browser shows, you can permanently trust that and proceed.

Comment: Yes, but I cannot expect every user to trust it. That is why I want to import a trustedCA in first place, so such warnings dont appear